# Optimize code for output multiple int variables into String

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, optimization

I have a few int variables declared:

```
[SerializeField] private int currentHP, currentMP, maxHP, maxMP, attack, intelligence, defense, speed, critChance;
```

And I would like to output them to a text that says "Your stat is xx". I have used the following code and **it works**:

```
if (maxHP > 0)
{
stats += string.Format("\n Your stat is {0}", maxHP);
}
```

However, I would like to know if there is a way to avoid copy paste this code for each int. Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: That depends on you desired output. Do you want method(s) for each possible stat or do you just want one method returning a string with all stats. Please add an example for the output to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, put every stat into an array:

```
int[] statsArray = { currentHP, currentMP, maxHP, maxMP, attack, intelligence, defense, speed, critChance };
```

Then, use a [LINQ query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/data-transformations-with-linq) to create a string for each stat. Note that you can make use of [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated):

```
var strings = from stat in statsArray 
                where stat > 0 // filters out the non-positive stats, like your if statement does
                select $"\nYour stat is {stat}."; // string interpolation
```

Then, join the strings together using `string.Concat`:

```
stats = string.Concat(strings);
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks :) this was exactly what I read yesterday (Interpolation) but didn't understand it completly, your example is perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way, without declaring your variables in another way, would be to create a function

```
private string GetStatString(int stat) {
    if (stat> 0)
    {
       return string.Format("\n Your stat is {0}", maxHP);
    }

    return "";
}
```

And in your code:

```
    stats += GetStatString(maxpHP) + GetStatString(maxMp); // etc
```

If you can add these into an array, then the work gets much easier, and you can combine with @Sweepers answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sweepers answer is probably the best approach.

However, if you really don't want to repeat yourself, not even the field names, you could use reflection to get all the `int`s in the class.

```cs
        var strings = GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance);
            .Select(field => field.GetValue(this))
            .OfType<int>()
            .Where(value => value > 0)
            .Select(value => $"Your stat is {value}");
        var concatenated = string.Join("\n", strings);
```

If you want to frequently iterate over all stats, perhaps it's better to use a dictionary, or a list of `string` and `int` tuples.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use System.Reflection in case you need to get the values during runtime without the need to put the fields in an array and to avoid adjusting your code to the print feature :

```
    public string GetStats()
    {
        string stats = string.Empty;

        // Get a list of FieldInfo objects.
        var fieldsInfo = GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic
                        | BindingFlags.Instance)
                        .Where(field => field.FieldType == typeof(int)).ToList();


        foreach (var field in fieldsInfo)
        {
            int fieldValue = (int)field.GetValue(this);

            if (fieldValue > 0)
            {
                stats += string.Format("\n Your stat is {0}", fieldValue);
            }
        }

        return stats;
    }
```